# global.asa didn't work to show display visitors

Tags: html, asp-classic, global.asa

When I try to display the unique visitor of my page, it doesn't show up.

**global.asa**

```
<SCRIPT RUNAT="Server" LANGUAGE="javascript">
    function Application_OnStart() {
        Application("visitors") = 0
    }

    function Application_OnEnd() {
        Application.Contents.RemoveAll()
    }

    function Session_OnStart() {
        Application.Lock
        Application("visitors") = Application("visitors") + 1
        Session.Timeout = 15
        Application.UnLock
    }

    function Session_OnEnd() {
        Application.Lock
        Application("visitors") = Application("visitors") - 1
        Application.UnLock
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

**display.asp**

```
There are <% Response.Write(Application("visitors")) %> online now!
```

It only shows "There are online now!" string. But there are no numbers and such.

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, it tested correctly.  Make sure you have the global.asa file in the root folder of the website.